# Is there a way to dynamically exclude operations from the execution path?

Tags: c#, multithreading, executable, .net-assembly

I am wondering if there is a way(shortcut) to dynamically exclude operations from the execution path of an assembly. For example, If I have a foreach loop such as the one below.

```
int count = 0;

foreach(char ch in myString){

if(count < 10){

// Do Something

++count;

}

// Do Something Else

}
```

Is there way to avoid checking if `count < 10` for every subsequent iteration? I suppose you could do this by jumping to another execution path, passing the enumerator as a parameter. Is there an elegant way to do this?

Comment: There are many ways to do so, each with their own drawbacks while hardly increasing readability. Why is checking `if (count < 10)` each iteration a problem?

Comment: set count to 10 and count down, now you can test if == 0 if you are averse to > operations. Or get the first 9 chars of myString into a separate string using substr

Comment: What does this have to do with multithreading?

Comment: Checking isn't really a problem. It just seems that checking millions of times versus the requirement of 10 is a waste, regardless of the overall timing costs.

Answer (score 0):

Use two loops :-)

```
// Process first 10 characters
for (int i = 0; i != Math.Min(myString.Length, 10); ++i) {
    var ch = myString[i];
    // Do something
}

// Process rest
for (int i = 10; i < myString.Length; ++i) {
    var ch = myString[i];
    // Do something else
}
```